# Searching interesting places on image for visual recognition process?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Imagine a huge 360° panoramic shot from security camera. I need to find people on this image. Suppose I already have some great classifier to tell if some picture is a picture of a single human being.

What I don't understand - is how to apply this classifier to the panoramic shot, which can contain multiple people? Should I apply it to all possible regions of the image? Or there is some way to search for "interesting points" and feed only regions around this points to my classifier?

Which keywords to google / algorythms to read about to find out ways to search regions of image, that may (or may not) contain information for following classification?

Comment: Try looking into face detection

Comment: Bag of Feature would be relevant too.